# Groups and Identity Inequality

Tags: group-theory

Let's say  $g,h \in G$ where $G$ is a group. $g$ is not the identity and $g^4h = hg^5$. I seek to prove that $gh \neq hg$.

I have tried to do it by contradiction, but Ive gotten nowhere. Any way I could prove this more directly?

Comment: If $g$ and $h$ commute then $g^4h=g^5h$, so $g=1$.

Comment: You can prove the contrapositive: if $gh = hg$ then $g$ is the identity. If $gh = hg$ then the given relation rearranges to $g^4 h = g^5 h$. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contradiction is definitely the way to go here. Assume $gh=hg$; do you see a way to use this to change (say) the right hand side into something more similar to the left hand side?

> Think about $$hg^5=hgg^4=ghg^4=ghgg^3=...$$ This will give you $$hg^5=g^5h.$$

The equation you get by changing the right hand side accordingly, namely

> $g^4h=g^5h$,

can then be hit with one of the group axioms to get a surprising fact:

> Using the fact that *inverses exist*, multiply both sides by $(g^4h)^{-1}$. What do you get?

Comment: As a logic-y aside, strictly speaking this isn't proof by contradiction but rather proof by *negation* - there is a [subtle difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104606/proof-by-contradiction-in-constructive-mathematics). But that's not really relevant here.

Comment: So nicely pedagogical that you could also use any $n$ and induction in the first spoiler.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction if $gh=hg$ then $g^4h=hg^4=hg^5$. Hence $g=1$, a contradiction.